# I have used <iFrame> tag in my react app but it will open the same file even the file url is different, but if I used <a> tag it open perfectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

item.image URL is coming form the API but when I try to map in `<a>` tag it will work fine which is for the download icon but for the view icon it will open the same file. [image]

```
data.map(item => {
 return <>
     <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal} center>
       <div className="modalContent">
           <iframe src={item?.image}>
           </iframe>      
       </div>
    </Modal>

 <a href={item?.image} target="_blank" download >
   <span className="IconBoc">
        <AiOutlineDownload />
    </span>
 </a>
</>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `<img>` instead of `<iframe>`.

iframes are to embed other websites into your website.

For media there already exist tags like `<img>` or `<video>`.

Try:

```js
data.map(item => {
 return <>
     <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal} center>
       <div className="modalContent">
           <img src={item?.image} />
       </div>
    </Modal>

 <a href={item?.image} target="_blank" download >
   <span className="IconBoc">
        <AiOutlineDownload />
    </span>
 </a>
</>
})
```